# Bootstrap / Wordpress: Search form with space values displays code from navigation

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Wordpress page using the Bootstrap framework. The normal search function works just fine, but if I search for spaces ("   ") or words with a space in the beginning or end it totally messes up my navigation on the page - the html code is displayed on the site and I think the search function searches for values in my navigation.

I tried to solve this by creating the search.php and header.php as new but that didn't work. As I used Bootstrap to create the page I had some issues changing the code for the Wordpress templates and it's possible that there could be the cause.

HTML code from my header.php file:

```
<div id="searchBox" class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-4">
   <div class="form-group">
       <div class="icon-addon addon">
           <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
           <input id="searchField" type="text" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars($s, 1); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
           <label id="searchIcon" for="search" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="Search..."></label>
           </form>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Code from my search.php file:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<div class="row">
   <content class="searchContent col-lg-7">
      <div id="leftContent" class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12">
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1><a href="?php the_permalink()?"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <div class="entry">
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
     <?php endwhile; ?>

      <p align="center"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; &Auml;ltere Eintr&auml;ge') ?> | <?php previous_posts_link('Neuere Eintr&auml;ge &raquo;') ?></p>
      </div>
   </content>
      <aside class="col-lg-3">
          <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
      </aside>
  </div>
<?php else : ?>
<div class="row">
  <div id="siteTitle" class="col-lg-6 ">
    <div  id="titleText" class="info col-lg-offset-11">
      <h1>Nothing found</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me solve this issue? I tried for hours and days but haven't found a solution yet. 
[Here an image of what my nav looks like if I search for values with spaces.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tuvV.png)

Comment: Is this live somewhere we can see it?

Comment: Yes, you can go and visit https://mediamatiker.ch/

Comment: I don't see any errors when I search, what can I try to reproduce the error?

Comment: Try to search for a value with spaces in the beginning or at the end (e.g. " search    ", or only for a few spaces "      " (without quotation marks).

Comment: Are php errors turned on? Can you turn them on for a minute?

Comment: ok should be turned on now

Comment: Being a wordpress issue, have you tried disabling all plugins or just one by one and performing a test search?

Comment: Yes, multiple times. Had no affect to the search

Comment: What if you switch to a default theme? Is your header nav custom coded? Since the error is there I'd look in those files as opposed to search.php. The error is only present in your nav, not body of search.

Comment: No, I can't switch to a default theme. The website is part of my apprenticeship (it's actually my first website) and I should get rid of that error if possible in any way

Comment: I'm suggesting you switch to a default theme for 5 minutes to see if the error is associated with the theme or not. This is a process of elimination. You can switch back to your own theme right after.

Comment: The search worked fine in the default theme, thank you! Now i can at least assume where the cause is.

Comment: Cool, then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the code you are using to highlight search terms in the copy.

When I search `test a test`, the letter A is made bold anywhere in the search results, as well as in the main nav. (It is wrapped with `<strong class="search-excerpt"></strong>`).

If I search `test g test`, the letter G is made bold. I think your site is not handling the `$_GET` values correctly, since it is only using the second value in the `$_GET['s']` array.

Searching your theme's codebase for `<strong class="search-excerpt">` should at least point you in the right direction of where the error is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! The issue was one line in my functions.php file with exactly the term "search-excerpt" in it. Changed a few things in this line and everything works fine now on the staging system.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, problem was caused by a custom theme, not aforementioned search form and search.php modifications.